# Chrome manifest v3 - is there a viable workaround to use Google's File Picker in a Chrome extension?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-sheets, manifest

My searches have turned up nothing concrete. My extension uses Google's file picker to allow the user to browse their sheets and choose a desired file to write some data to, which manifest v3 breaks because of some GAPI limitations. Unless I've missed something obvious, there does not seem to be a simple workaround or method for this to migrate to v3 -- it just seems to be disallowed.

I'm not asking if there's a way to do something that they intend to not be possible (even though I doubt such a thing would exist with Google) but I'm optimistically hoping that maybe there is some hacky/annoying workaround that still fits within their rules. If I absolutely have to just allow them to set a sheet URL manually I will...I'm just trying to avoid it.

Any tips or  suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is breaking in v3 or what API limitations are you finding? Is it not included in the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/)?

Comment: @Daniel they just straight up blocked the ability to use any external scripts...even ones that Google created and owns. So like oauth still works because it's built into Chrome, but any script that requires an external HTTP request is a no go. At least that's what I've read, but I was hoping there was some weird circumstance that would allow file picker to be used if you do some goofy thing you'd never think of without being told.

Comment: You may have been misled a little there, HTTP requests are not disallowed, but rather external script files and `eval()` code are blocked now. So you can have code that makes HTTP requests such as making API calls, but not calls that load entire script files. This means that if you include the libraries in your project they can still call the API. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Let me know if this helped you or if you had additional feedback. If this answered your question you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so this can help other people in the community who may have the same concern as you.

Comment: @neonfontana did you find a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  may have to test it yourself to make sure there are no weird behaviors, but Google has some recommendations regarding this in their [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code):

> In Manifest V3, all of your extension's logic must be included in the extension. You can no longer load and execute a remotely hosted file. A number of alternative approaches are available, depending on your use case and the reason for remote hosting. Here are approaches to consider:
>
> ###### Configuration-driven features and logic
>
> In this approach, your extension loads a remote configuration (for example a JSON file) at runtime and caches the configuration locally. The extension then uses this cached configuration to decide which features to enable.
>
> ###### Externalize logic with a remote service
>
> Consider migrating application logic from the extension to a remote web service that your extension can call. (Essentially a form of message passing.) This provides you the ability to keep code private and change the code on demand while avoiding the extra overhead of resubmitting to the Chrome Web Store.
>
> ###### Bundle third-party libraries
>
> If you are using a popular framework like React or Bootstrap, you can download the minified files, add them to your project and import them locally.

For your case, option #3 seems like the easiest. Looking at the Google Picker API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview) it only uses two relatively small script files, `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` and `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`. You could try to bundle these in your Chrome extension and call the methods locally.

Comment: Wow, I did so much searching and it did not occur to me that there was such an API with a script I can host locally. I am going to test this and see if it works okay on v3. 

I am also unsure of the "mark as answered" etiquette in this situation, because I am actually not sure if this will work on v3 without testing it, but it seems like it should be okay, so i'll mark it.

thank you very much for the info.

Comment: it does not look like it will work, the js file in the script would have to be stored locally, which is fine, but it appears to download and execute a larger js file, which is not possible. very frustrating

Comment: ...another follow up. I have no idea, actually. I am going to try.